# How to apply an image map in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

My HTML file has an image map as follows:

```
<map name="map" id="map">
    <area id="area" href="" shape="rect" coords="178,68,199,82" />
</map>
```

In the JavaScript file, I have a function that creates an image in `div` element with `id` of `imageSection`:

```
function showImg(index) {
   var randomImgIndex = randomInteger(index);
   var imageSectionDiv = document.getElementById("imageSection");
   imageSectionDiv.style.backgroundImage = 'url(../images/img' + randomImgIndex + '.jpg)';
   imageSectionDiv.id = "myImg"

   document.getElementById("area").href = '../images/img' + randomImgIndex + '.jpg';
   document.getElementById("area").onclick = startTest;
   document.getElementById("myImg").useMap = "#map";

   return randomImgIndex;
}
```

Here, `randomInteger` is a function to generate a random int in the range `[0, index]` and `startTest` is a custom function.

The problem is that this code does not work. I expect to see a change of the mouse pointer once I hover it on the specified image area (because of onclickevent), but this does not happen. Any ideas why?

P.S. please, do not use any JQuery, as I am only familiar with pure JavaScript. Thank you!

Comment: *"I have a function that creates an image in div element with id of imageSection"* - when you look closely, you don't have that.

Comment: Why would you get the event to trigger on `hover` when you register on `click`? Try `.onmouseover` instead.

Comment: @Tomalak True, he does not. But he do set the `background` of it to an image.

Comment: I see. So, I am actually trying to apply an image map to a background image. Should I create am `img` object and append it as a child to `div`? And then apply the image map to it?

Comment: Thank you, Tomalak. I redefined my function so that it actually creates an img element and appends it to the div node. Then I was able to apply the map to that img child.

Comment: Good to hear that it was that easy. You can either delete this question (as it is based on a simple mistake) or write and accept your own answer.